# How can I assign a numerical value to every word in a text file or user input in java

Tags: java

im still new to programming so i only know little java.

I was wondering how to write a method that would either take a text file or user input and assign a number to every word with the first word being 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a StringTokenizer to do this. Here is an example program that you can run to see how it works. If you want to read from a file then you need to learn how to turn the file into a String, then you just pass that string into the makeWordItemsFromString method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class StringTokenizerDemo
{
    private static class WordItem
    {
        public int id;
        public String word;

        public WordItem(int id, String word)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.word = word;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String text = "this is my text";
        List<WordItem> wordItems = makeWordItemsFromString(text);

        //Loop over them and print them out, or do whatever you like here
        for(WordItem wordItem : wordItems)
        {
            System.out.println(wordItem.word + "(" + wordItem.id + ")");
        }
    }

    private static List<WordItem> makeWordItemsFromString(String text)
    {
        int count = 1;
        List<WordItem> wordItems = new ArrayList<>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(text);
        while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            wordItems.add(new WordItem(count++, tokenizer.nextToken()));
        }
        return wordItems;
    }
}
```